# How to sort open weather map API response when you request 2+ days of forecast

Tags: python, openweathermap

Hello guys this is my first post.
I'm struggling real hard with this.
When you ask for multiple days forecast the array is a real headache
it looks like this:

```
{
  "city": {
    "id": 261779,
    "name": "Ioannina",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 20.8508,
      "lat": 39.6675
    },
    "country": "GR",
    "population": 64012,
    "timezone": 7200
  },
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 1.6748099,
  "cnt": 3,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1581674400,
      "sunrise": 1581658280,
      "sunset": 1581696629,
      "temp": {
        "day": 5.85,
        "min": 5.34,
        "max": 6.89,
        "night": 6.73,
        "eve": 6.19,
        "morn": 5.34
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 3.07,
        "night": 5.55,
        "eve": 3.59,
        "morn": 3.04
      },
      "pressure": 1019,
      "humidity": 97,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 502,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "heavy intensity rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "speed": 2.49,
      "deg": 197,
      "clouds": 100,
      "rain": 38.63
    },
    {
      "dt": 1581760800,
      "sunrise": 1581744606,
      "sunset": 1581783100,
      "temp": {
        "day": 8.65,
        "min": 3.92,
        "max": 10.93,
        "night": 3.92,
        "eve": 9.52,
        "morn": 5.04
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 5.27,
        "night": 0.66,
        "eve": 6.49,
        "morn": 1.8
      },
      "pressure": 1020,
      "humidity": 67,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "sky is clear",
          "icon": "01d"
        }
      ],
      "speed": 2.65,
      "deg": 31,
      "clouds": 4
    },
    {
      "dt": 1581847200,
      "sunrise": 1581830931,
      "sunset": 1581869570,
      "temp": {
        "day": 9.25,
        "min": 2.54,
        "max": 11.97,
        "night": 3.2,
        "eve": 10.1,
        "morn": 2.62
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 7.09,
        "night": 0.06,
        "eve": 8.26,
        "morn": -0.71
      },
      "pressure": 1028,
      "humidity": 57,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "speed": 0.5,
      "deg": 59,
      "clouds": 31
    }
  ]
}
```

I have one week struggling to separate the forecast of each day seperately. and then print some basic values on my program like temp and humidity for example.
Also I'm using tkinter to build a GUI to show every day's forecast.'

If you'd like to see the code of the program: https://github.com/zafalex88/open_weather_project/

Every opinion is welcomed.

Thank you in advance!
Alex

Comment: `data['list'][0]`, `data['list'][1]`, etc. or with loop `for day in data['list']: print(day['weather'], day[0]['description'])`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is customary to include the relevant piece of code in the question itself, so people don't have to go to other sites. Also, it's a bit hard to see just from the json output how you want to sort it. Can you reduce the size of your example and add your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can print

```
print( data['list'][0]['humidity'] )
print( data['list'][1]['humidity'] )
```

or using loop

```
for day in data['list']:
    print('humidity:', day['humidity'])
```

---

Minimal working example - it also use `datetime` to convert `dt` (timestamp) to date

```
import datetime

data = {"city":{"id":261779,"name":"Ioannina","coord":{"lon":20.8508,"lat":39.6675},"country":"GR","population":64012,"timezone":7200},"cod":"200","message":1.6748099,"cnt":3,"list":[{"dt":1581674400,"sunrise":1581658280,"sunset":1581696629,"temp":{"day":5.85,"min":5.34,"max":6.89,"night":6.73,"eve":6.19,"morn":5.34},"feels_like":{"day":3.07,"night":5.55,"eve":3.59,"morn":3.04},"pressure":1019,"humidity":97,"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":2.49,"deg":197,"clouds":100,"rain":38.63},{"dt":1581760800,"sunrise":1581744606,"sunset":1581783100,"temp":{"day":8.65,"min":3.92,"max":10.93,"night":3.92,"eve":9.52,"morn":5.04},"feels_like":{"day":5.27,"night":0.66,"eve":6.49,"morn":1.8},"pressure":1020,"humidity":67,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":2.65,"deg":31,"clouds":4},{"dt":1581847200,"sunrise":1581830931,"sunset":1581869570,"temp":{"day":9.25,"min":2.54,"max":11.97,"night":3.2,"eve":10.1,"morn":2.62},"feels_like":{"day":7.09,"night":0.06,"eve":8.26,"morn":-0.71},"pressure":1028,"humidity":57,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"speed":0.5,"deg":59,"clouds":31}]}

for day in data['list']:

    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(day['dt'])
    print('date:', date)

    print('humidity:', day['humidity'])

    #print('temp:', day['temp'])
    print('temp day:', day['temp']['day'])
    print('temp min:', day['temp']['min'])
    print('temp max:', day['temp']['max'])
```

Result:

```
date: 2020-02-14 11:00:00
humidity: 97
temp day: 5.85
temp min: 5.34
temp max: 6.89
date: 2020-02-15 11:00:00
humidity: 67
temp day: 8.65
temp min: 3.92
temp max: 10.93
date: 2020-02-16 11:00:00
humidity: 57
temp day: 9.25
temp min: 2.54
temp max: 11.97
```

---

Minimal example with `tkinter`

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

data = {"city":{"id":261779,"name":"Ioannina","coord":{"lon":20.8508,"lat":39.6675},"country":"GR","population":64012,"timezone":7200},"cod":"200","message":1.6748099,"cnt":3,"list":[{"dt":1581674400,"sunrise":1581658280,"sunset":1581696629,"temp":{"day":5.85,"min":5.34,"max":6.89,"night":6.73,"eve":6.19,"morn":5.34},"feels_like":{"day":3.07,"night":5.55,"eve":3.59,"morn":3.04},"pressure":1019,"humidity":97,"weather":[{"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"heavy intensity rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":2.49,"deg":197,"clouds":100,"rain":38.63},{"dt":1581760800,"sunrise":1581744606,"sunset":1581783100,"temp":{"day":8.65,"min":3.92,"max":10.93,"night":3.92,"eve":9.52,"morn":5.04},"feels_like":{"day":5.27,"night":0.66,"eve":6.49,"morn":1.8},"pressure":1020,"humidity":67,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":2.65,"deg":31,"clouds":4},{"dt":1581847200,"sunrise":1581830931,"sunset":1581869570,"temp":{"day":9.25,"min":2.54,"max":11.97,"night":3.2,"eve":10.1,"morn":2.62},"feels_like":{"day":7.09,"night":0.06,"eve":8.26,"morn":-0.71},"pressure":1028,"humidity":57,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"speed":0.5,"deg":59,"clouds":31}]}

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='humidity').pack()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

for day in data['list']:
    #listbox.insert('end', day['humidity'])
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(day['dt'])
    text = '{}: {}'.format(date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d'), day['humidity'])
    listbox.insert('end', text)


root.mainloop()
```